# Getting a "EXC_BAD_ERROR" signal after changing UIDatePicker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I can click a button to save the date from the date picker just fine, but when i try changing that value afterwards, it will randomly at some point give an "EXC_BAD_ERROR" signal. Why could this be?

Comment: Can you post the block of code where it crashes.

Comment: It crashes when i'm changing the value, and the value changed option on the UIDatePicker isn't hooked up to anything. So i don't know what code it could be going through to cause an error.

Answer (score 1):

Use NSZombiesEnabled to find the cause of problem, and see them in debugger.

Go to XCode -> Projects -> Edit Active Executable "YourProjectName" -> Arguments tab -> go to ' Variables to be set in environment' -> add variable "NSZombiesEnabled" and put its value to "YES" and also don't forget to check the checkmark.

Then debug the code and see in debugger at the time of crash what is the cause of this error.

Comment: I still only got "Debugging terminated" in the bar across the bottom, nothing in the actual debugger.

Answer (score 1):

Its highly likely that you are keeping the date provided as a reference and so when the memory harvester destroys the picker at some random time the date ref is vanishing and causing your crash.

You want to make a copy of the date provided by the picker.

Either property wise

`@property (readwrite,copy) NSDate *thedate;`

or just

`thedate = [thepicker.date copy];`

for both those, release in the dealloc override.

as in

```
-(void)dealloc
{
[thedate release];
[super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: As it happens at random, I can't be sure that's fixed it, but it doesn't seem to be happening any more so I'll assume it has for now. Thanks.

Comment: Using that second method, what code would i use to release it?

Comment: see edit above , for both methods , 1 is better if you need other objects to have access to the date or the date repeatedly changes in your object . The mem control will be handled by the accessor self.thedate = thepicker.date. If it only sets once the 2 is fine.